# JComboBox: Not editable but typeable

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

In my application, there is a JComboBox featuring about 200 entries. The people working with the application complain that it is frustrating to have to  scroll all the way to the bottom, even though they know exactly what the last element of the list is.

So I went and made the JComboBox editable, so they can just type in this last element. However, my database does not accept any values other than featured in the dropdown of this combobox.

Is there a way to make the JComboBox only "typeable" instead of "editable", so it will let you type in values, but only as long as they match at least 1 item in the dropdown?

**Edit:**
As is turns out, the above demanded feature is already implemented per se. My application, however, is using custom code that somehow disables it. I cannot figure out where it happens ... as a matter of fact, I don't see at all what the below code is doing exactly.

**Edit2:**
I did some testing (took me quite some time) and figured out, that it is not my custom code that's disabling the feature. In fact, it was a somehow faulty implementation of the combobox-filling ComboBoxModel that prevented the jumping somehow.

I can now type c and it jumps to the first entry beginning with c. **However**, I cannot type " " (space), because then the popup is going to close. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865035/searching-jcomboboxes-with-multi-word-elements) answer, but it seems overly complicated. Isn't there an easier way to do it?

Comment: `JComboBox` is "typeable" by default. If you focus it and start typing, it will jump to the element that starts with what you type, although what you type is not visible.

Comment: @icza I don't think it's the case here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#editable

Comment: @joeyrohan that behavior depends on the Look & Feel I think. It certainly works in Windows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using windows, (Win 7 32-bit JDK 7)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so what you're saying is that if I change they Look&Feel to Windows, it will work they way I want? It currently is one of the "ugly" Java-looking application, and it isn't working. Are you sure that changing this will help?

Comment: @Marco7757 try adding nimbus

Comment: @Marco7757 it certainly works for me when using the Windows LnF.

Comment: @Marco7757, it works using Windows, Metal and Nimbus which are all the LAF I can text on a Window machine. I would be extremely surprised if it doesn't work on Mac, Linux etc., because this behaviour should be standard on all platforms. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)demonstrating the problem along with OS information if you still have problems. You should post a SSCCE with all your questions so we don't need to guess what you are doing.

Comment: @camickr Not working for me :O windows LAF or Nimbus??

Comment: @joeyrohan, once again "not working" doesn't mean anything unless a `SSCCE` is posted showing the code used. If it doesn't work then you probably have some custom code you are using for your combo box. This is default functionality.

Comment: @camickr is correct; it works as expected on `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`.

Comment: confirmed, it really does. The application is indeed using custom code I didn't write (I'm just recently took over development). It uses something my predecessor called a "BetterJComboBox". Can somebody figure out why the changes he made make this feature not working? (code above)

Comment: I'm wondering how in Earth loosing a default feature might be considered a *BetterJComboBox*. On th other hand I think the problem could be the combo box renderer: see [this post](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) by @camickr.

Comment: @dic19, `I think the problem could be the combo box renderer` - that would be my guess as well. I'm still waiting for the OP to post a proper `SSCCE`,  so we have all the information. I get frustrated when people expect us to keep guessing what their code is really doing...

Comment: `I'm wondering how in Earth loosing a default feature might be considered a BetterJComboBox` Unfortunately, despite my breath-holding and temper tantrums, I can relate to this first-hand.

Comment: Seems the custom code wasn't the issue after all. I got it to work. Sorry for wasting everybody's time :(

Answer (score 1):

As [icza mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384294/jcombobox-not-editable-but-typeable/26416422#comment41423188_26384294):

> `JComboBox` is "typeable" by default. If you focus it and start typing, it will jump to the element that starts with what you type, although what you type is not visible.

you are describing the default behavior of a combo box. The following example does exactly what you described (Obtained from the Oracle Java tutorial website):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboBoxDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    public ComboBoxDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        String[] petStrings = { "Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Duck", "Rabbit", "Pig" };
        JComboBox<String> petList = new JComboBox<String>(petStrings);
        petList.setSelectedIndex(0);
        petList.addActionListener(this);
        add(petList, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox<String> cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        String petName = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println("You selected: " + petName);
    }
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JComponent newContentPane = new ComboBoxDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

A couple of people are suggesting you might have a problem with the combo box renderer, and I think they might be right. Anyway, run this example and verify for yourself that it behaves as intended. When you verify this, update this example and use your renderer. If it stops behaving as before, then you will know for certain where your problem lies.